# Is it possible to count the number of SQL queries with Flask / SQLAlchemy / Pytest / SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, select-n-plus-1

I have a Flask project which uses SQLAlchemy and a database. For testing, I replace the database by an SQLite database.

Now I would like to run some of the views and test for the number of queries executed. Essentially, I want to avoid to accidentially run into the (n+1) select problem. Is it possible to get the number of executed SQL Queries from SQLite or a Pytest / Flask plugin?

Comment: Similar-ish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073099/how-to-count-sqlalchemy-queries-in-unit-tests

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/events.html (logging events)

`event.listen(engine, "before_cursor_execute")`

Now you can use the function as mentioned in the documentation :

````
    @event.listens_for(conn, 'before_cursor_execute')
    def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters,
                                    context, executemany):
        log.info("Received statement: %s", statement)```
````