# Does the sqlalchemy make additional requests when we work with query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and I have a question regarding my code:

```
query = db.query(Purchase.name,
                 func.sum(Purchase.price).label('total'),
                 func.count(Purchase.name).label('count'))

if date_start and date_end:
    query = query.filter(Purchase.date >= date_start,
                         Purchase.date <= date_end)

query = query.group_by(Purchase.name)\
             .order_by(sqlalchemy.desc('total'))[:limit]

result = [ItemDict(name=item.name, total=item.total,
                   count=item.count) for item in query]
```

Do I understand correctly that:

1. In this program there will be only one query to the database?
2. When we work with Query objects, we do NOT make additional queries to the database (i.e. the expression in the list does not make additional queries)?

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 1: Yes, there should be only one query (there may also be a small query that does the "ping" command depending on your pool configuration)

Ad. 2: Additional queries depends on joining strategy. If you filter only one model without joining, you should always have single query. However, if you join other models and use lazy joining strategy, you can have many implicit additional queries (my short [post](https://jorzel.hashnode.dev/an-orm-can-bite-you) about it)

You can use this smart context manager to count number of queries: [How to count sqlalchemy queries in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073099/how-to-count-sqlalchemy-queries-in-unit-tests).

Comment: Thank you so much. 

To get rid of implicit queries it is enough to make JOIN?

Comment: No, sometimes you have to also add `contains_eager` or `joinedload` but it depends on how you filtering. Look at the example in the post: https://jorzel.hashnode.dev/an-orm-can-bite-you. `join` and `outerjoin` influence only your filtering, but not query results.